# Write a slice of any type to a file in Go

Tags: go

For logging purposes I want to be able to quickly write a slice of any type, whether it be ints, strings, or custom structs, to a file in Go. For instance, in C#, I can do the following in 1 line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, myCustomTypeList.Select(x => x.ToString());
```

How would I go about doing this in Go? The structs implement the `Stringer` interface.

Edit: I in particular would like the output to be printed to a file and one line per item in the slice

Answer (score 7):

Use the [fmt](https://godoc.org/fmt) package format values as strings and print to a file:

```
func printLines(filePath string, values []interface{}) error {
    f, err := os.Create(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    for _, value := range values {
       fmt.Fprintln(f, value)  // print values to f, one per line
    }
    return nil
}
```

`fmt.Fprintln` will call `Stringer()` on your struct type. It will also print `int` values and `string` values.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/QsPFwAlxyr)

Use the reflect package to write any slice type:

```
func printLines(filePath string, values interface{}) error {
  f, err := os.Create(filePath)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  defer f.Close()
  rv := reflect.ValueOf(values)
  if rv.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
    return errors.New("Not a slice")
  }
  for i := 0; i < rv.Len(); i++ {
    fmt.Fprintln(f, rv.Index(i).Interface())
  }
  return nil
}
```

If you have variable `values` of type `myCustomList`, then you can call it like this: `err := printLines(filePath, values)`

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/rHTjmbQmqs)

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, but how would I go about putting this into a wrapper function. For instance, what would the type be for myCustomList if I wanted to pass it to a function, along with the file path

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't use `range` on something of type `interface{}`. It doesn't compile.

Comment: @Andy Schweig You're correct, this doesn't work. If I use a type assertion on value aka `value.(string)` then the function compiles, but then I can't pass in a slice of any type into the function without the compiler complaining. Looks like the most idiomatic solution is to just create helper functions for all the types I use.